# Wowza automatic/scripted addition of SDP streams

Tags: video-streaming, rtp, wowza, sdp

Here is the Wowza's doc explaining how to add incoming RTP streams:

https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?38-How-to-set-up-live-streaming-using-a-native-RTP-encoder-with-SDP-file

that includes steps:

> In the Server contents panel, click Stream Files, and then click the
> Connect icon for the myStream.sdp file.
>
> In the Connect a Stream File dialog box, select live in Application Name and
> rtp in MediaCaster Type, and then click OK.

I am using this to receive the stream (and then let users play it through different protocols), not publish, but anyway, it works fine.

What i am wondering though, is there any way to automate/script it? I need to add these streams by the hundreds all the time so there is no way to do it manually? Maybe some kind of API?

Comment: I know how to do it with .stream files, but now with .sdp files. Just
for instance. Maybe i need to make a .stream file that complements or replaces .sdp file? How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Solution was to create a .stream file which contains nothing but the name and extension of the SDP file. Stupid as it sounds, it helped.